# How to know if I a clone was done from fork or from origin on git?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I've `cloned` a repo months ago and would like to know if it was done from my fork or from the original repository. Which git subcommand should I run to get the answer?

Comment: can you please elaborate what must appear in the output and publish it as an answer? I'll approve it :)

Comment: This is a very basic question that the manual can solve. SO is not a substitute for that.

Comment: Not that basic to me and not that easy scanned through a manual :) Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: It's not something to be gleaned by scanning but something that you'll get it you read the manual.

Comment: By reading the manual completely there would be much less need in stackoverflow, I guess our visions diverge. To note, there is a ton of tremendously popular howto questions. We'd better wrap up here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `origin` remote will be the repository cloned from.

To see the list of remotes in the repository use `git remote -v`.  This should be enough to know where it is was cloned from, but to see more details about a specific remote use `git remote -v show <remote name>`.